# shutil.move() method in shutil module in Python

Tags: python, bash, os.system, shutil

Does shutil.move(src, dest) method call the os.system() method or the bash commands 'mv' and 'cp'?

P.S : I searched on the net but couldn't find any helpful info.

Comment: what if you run it on windows or anywhere there is no bash shell?

Comment: actually my program is meant to run in a bash shell. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the source Luke:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py

it actually does neither.
if you follow the code, it ends up opening a new file descriptor and writing buffered bytes to it.  like this:

```
while 1:
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
    if not buf:
        break
    fdst.write(buf)
```